# Particle Physics: Understanding the Jacobian peak

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, weak-interaction

The Jacobian peak is relevant when one tries to measure the $W$ boson mass, because we cannot detect neutrinos in hadron colliders directly.

Now, if we look at e. g. the decay $W^{+}\rightarrow \mu^{+}\nu_{\mu}$, the transverse momentum spectrum of the $\mu^{+}$ shows a clear peak at $p_t = m_W/2$, and apparently this can be proved by showing that

$$\frac{dN}{dp_t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left( m_w /2 \right)^2 - p_t^2}} \frac{dN}{d\theta^{*}}.$$ However, I am unfortunately not sure yet on how to derive this relation, could anybody please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for:

$$ \frac{d\theta^*}{dp_t} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{(\frac 1 2 M_W)^2-p_t^2}}$$

In the C.O.M frame, with $E \gg m_{\mu}$:

$$E_{\mu}+E_{\nu} = 2E=2p = M_W$$

so

$$\sqrt{(\frac 1 2 M_W)^2-p_t^2} =\sqrt{p^2-p_t^2}=p_L$$

Also:

$$p_t = p\sin{\theta^*}$$

and
$$ p_L = p\cos{\theta^*}$$

(the definitions of transverse and longitudinal), you get:

$$ \frac{dp_t}{d\theta^*} = p\cos{\theta^*} = p_L$$

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question!